# How to get database credentials from property file?

Tags: java, mysql

I am using a MySQL database and, currently, have hardcoded strings for the URL, Username, and Password. I am attempting to learn how to better manage these credentials by using a property file but can't figure out how to properly do this despite many days of google searches and reviewing many similar questions on SO.

I am currently doing this:

```
private CreateConnection() throws SQLException {
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("URL", "user", "password");
}
```

I have defined a properties file as follows but don't know how to keep this information secret and then reference it in my getConnection operation. What is the best way to do this? I have also tried to find a way to get the credentials from the Data Source Properties file in intellij but I am not sure if that's even possible.

```
# MySQL
db.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cafe?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC
db.user=root
db.password=root
```

Comment: Perhaps you need method [load](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.InputStream-)? Or maybe Oracle's [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html)?

Comment: can use vault https://www.vaultproject.io/